# Understanding the one sentence proof that every prime 1 more than a muliple of 4 is the sum of 2 squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This [proof](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2323918/fulltext.pdf) is credited to Don Zagier. It goes like this:

Consider the finite set $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : x^2+4yz=p\}$ where p is a prime. Then consider the following involution:

$$(x,y,z) \mapsto
\begin{cases} 
     (x + 2z, z, y - x + z) & x< y-z \\
     (2y - x, y, x - y + z) & y-z<x<2y \\
     (x - 2y, x - y + z, y) & x > 2y 
   \end{cases}$$
It's not difficult to see that this function is an involution and that it has at least one fixed point of the form $(x,x,k)$. But Zagier says that there is exactly one fixed point, $(1,1,k)$, which shows that the cardinality of $S$ is odd and $$(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,z,y)$$
Also has exactly one fixed point, which concludes the proof.

The part that I'm uncomfortable with is $(1,1,k)$ being the only fixed point. I assume its based on the definition of $S$. In the defining equation for $S$, $x$ must be odd because otherwise $x^2$ would be a multiple of 4 and the left side of the equation would not be prime. I'm not sure how all other possible values for $x$ are excluded though. Clarification or hints would be appreciated.

This is different from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052461/on-zagiers-one-liner-on-fermats-theorem) because I grasp the strategy of the proof I am just wondering about this particular detail.

Comment: Suppose that $(x,x,k) \in S$. Then $$x^2+4xk=p$$ In particular this implies that $x$ divides $p$ (and it is strictly smaller than $p$). Thus, since $p$ is prime, it is only possible that $x=1$.

Comment: Ohhh, you might as well turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(x,x,k)∈S$. Then
$$x^2+4xk=p$$
In particular this implies that $x$ divides $p$ (and it is strictly smaller than $p$). Thus, since $p$ is prime, it is only possible that $x=1$.